# Подключение к удаленной postgresql из Pycharm

Tags: postgresql, centos, postgresql9.5

Добрый день! У нас есть сервер для разработки на котором установлена Centos 7 и postgres-9.5, не получается в Pycharm подключиться к удаленному серверу.

Конфиг /var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data/pg_hba.conf после добавления последней строки выглядит так:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            password
host    all             all             ::1/128                 password
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

iptables временно отключили

В Pycharm далаю такую конфигурацию
[image: Настройки pycharm]